# How can I detect if user is using autocomplete on text field?

Tags: javascript

I recently moved to using `<a>` tags as submit buttons for styling purposes.
I have a JS plugin I wrote that handles forms and their validation.

To simulate a normal form, where a user hits enter on a text field to submit, I detect enter and submit form on keyup.

The problem is if the user hits enter in an autocomplete dropdown from Firefox, for instance, it detects and still tries to submit the form.

Any ideas? I might switch to my form handler appending a hidden submit button in the event one is not found for the form....

Comment: The fact that an <a> is being used, it's not working by default. That's why I think we're gonna have our plugin automatically add a hidden submit. That gets around it.

Comment: In your keyUp listener can't you detect whether or not the drop down has focus and act accordingly?

Comment: @mattacular wouldn't you have to have focus on the element for a keyUp event to fire?

Comment: "I recently moved to using <a> tags as submit buttons for styling purposes." — a kitten loses all its fur whenever someone does that.

Comment: If you want styling, use a `button` although using an anchor tag isn't truly terrible for this purpose...  using correct tags is crucial for viewing across multiple browsers and devices.

Comment: We got to using an <a> tag since we read this article where Google has veered away from <button> for styling: http://stopdesign.com/archive/2009/02/04/recreating-the-button.html <a> tags are much more easily, and consistently styled than inputs across browserse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply made my validation plugin automatically look for a submit button, if one is not present, it adds it and styles it to be -9999px top and left, absolute. This way if a user hits submit, the native action is taken. I can't just use display:none on the button or some browsers won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

You could watch for the up or down arrow, and once pressed set an inAutoComplete flag.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var autoCompleteActive = false;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 38:
            case 40: autoCompleteActive = true; 
            break;
            default: autoCompleteActive = false;
            break;
        }

        if(e.keyCode==13 && !autoCompleteActive) {
            //do your onEnter stuff
        }
    });
});
```

However, if a user presses the down arrow without the autocomplete window popping up, they will need to press enter twice before it gets submitted.

You might want to consider scripting your own autocomplete or using the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) to gain more control over the autocomplete window.

Comment: I got side-tracked at work but I'll be trying this solution out. Although I might take away the enter key listener in favor of placing a hidden submit button which would do the trick, I think with less effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can override autocomplete behavior to turn it off.

```
<form autocomplete="off">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this not work?

```
    var hasFocus = false;
    $('#yourAutoCompleteElement').focusin(function () {
       hasFocus = true;
    });

    $('#yourAutoCompleteElement').focusout(function () {
       hasFocus = false;
    });

    $('#yourAtagSubmit').keyUp(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == ENTER && !hasFocus) {
           // submit
        }

        return;
    });
```

Edit: It is really bad practice to use A tag submit buttons. You should be able to style a regular submit button in the same fashion, and it will work across all devices.